# Sort pandas dataframe by index then by alphabetical order

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sort a dataframe by index, and then by alphabetical order, in case some index values are identical.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['values'] = ['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
df['index'] = [2, 0, 1, 0]
df = df.set_index('index')

df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Which output

```
      values
index       
0          c
0          a
1          b
2          d
```

However, I am expecting:

```
      values
index       
0          a
0          c
1          b
2          d
```

Is there any way to achieve this consistently  ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), you can pass the index name into `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values(['index','values'])
```

Output:

```
      values
index       
0          a
0          c
1          b
2          d
```

**Fun**: You can also sort by values, then sort again by index with a stable algorithm:

```
df.sort_values('values').sort_index(kind='mergesort')
```